# My laptop is getting really hot after installing Ubuntu

Tags: overheating

I know that this question has been asked often here but I need you guys to help!
After installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS my Laptop is getting so hot!

The laptop details are:

- Intel Pentinum T4500 2,3  GHZ,
- Ati Mobility Radeon HD 4570
- 4GB  DDR3

If you could find a solution please tell me in steps!

I also installed the Driver from ATI no change :L

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! For this to be answerable separately from the other questions about overheating, you'll have to *edit your question* to tell us what you tried from the answers to those questions (and to provide the kind of information that people requested in *those* answers), and what happened. Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the proprietary ATI drivers? Some users have said it helps control temperatures.

Comment: Could you say me how please? :L